# How do I use the Yelp API in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, api, yelp

I don't know Objective-C. They have no code samples on their page for Swift. Has anyone used their new V2 API with Swift yet who can provide some examples or simple searches such as querying local restaurants nearby and more importantly how to provide their required keys?

Comment: They give examples in Objective-C, just take those and convert them to swift. If you have any problems with that, come back with a specific question about your attempt at converting the code.

Comment: I don't know any Objective-C unfortunately, I began coding in iOS back in December when Swift tutorials became available.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://github.com/codepath/ios_yelp_swift

> ## Basic Yelp client
>
> This is a headless example of how to implement an OAuth 1.0a Yelp API
> client. The Yelp API provides an application token that allows
> applications to make unauthenticated requests to their search API.
>
> ## Next steps
>
> Check out BusinessesViewController.swift to see how to use the
> Business model. Sample request
>
> Basic search with query
>
> ```
> Business.searchWithTerm("Thai", completion: { (businesses: [Business]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
>     self.businesses = businesses
>
>     for business in businesses {
>         print(business.name!)
>         print(business.address!)
>     }
> })
> ```
>
> Advanced search with categories, sort, and deal filters
>
> ```
> Business.searchWithTerm("Restaurants", sort: .Distance, categories: ["asianfusion", "burgers"], deals: true) { (businesses: [Business]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
>
>     for business in businesses {
>         print(business.name!)
>         print(business.address!)
>     }
> }
> ```